# why does redirecting stdout to result of memfd_create() only appear to work if stdout is used beforehand?

Tags: c, linux

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a 64-bit machine.

I want to redirect `stdout` to the descriptor obtained from `memfd_create`. It seems the anonymous file created with `memfd_create` only gets the content if `stdout` gets a non-empty output before `dup2()` used for redirection.  Why??

Here is the SSCCU:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE        
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int temp_fd = memfd_create("temp", 0);
    struct stat sb;

    printf("a\n");
    dup2(temp_fd, 1);
    printf("b\n");
    fstat(temp_fd, &sb);
    fprintf(stderr, "%lu\n", sb.st_size);
}
```

Here, 2 is printed, as expected, as the `b\n` gets to the anonymous file.

However, if we remove `printf("a\n");`
then 0 is printed.

Why?

If we replace `printf("a\n")` with `fflush(stdout)` or `printf("")` still 0 is printed.

If we replace with `printf("a");` then 3 is printed, as expected.

It seems one has to print a non-empty string to `stdout` before `dup2`.

Edit (after the answer):  what is the relevance of `memfd_create()`? Well, without this, the output file is not anonymous and volatile, so I just checked the result by hand afterwards and everything is fine.

Comment: have you tried `fflush(stdout)` after printing b ? linefeed doesn't necessarily mean flush, specially when the output is redirected

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes it works!  but why would it also work if we print, like `a` beforehand??

Comment: @MarkGaleck I bet the first time you print something libc checks whether fd 1 is a terminal or not, and if it's a terminal, it uses line buffering

Comment: @user253751 oh this is sick :)  please make it an aswer I will accept it

Comment: to make it an answer I would have to check it's actually correct

Comment: @user253751 You nailed it.  Running the code posted under `strace` shows `3965831 fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x1), ...}) = 0` immediately before the write to file descriptor 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your version of libc checks whether FD 1 is a terminal or not, right before the first time it prints something. If it's a terminal, it sets up line buffering, so the buffer is flushed every time a newline is printed. Otherwise, full buffering, so it's only flushed when full.

This isn't guaranteed behaviour. It's just what the version of libc installed on your computer does.

If you want to flush the buffer at any specific time you can use `fflush(stdout)`. Or you can use `setvbuf` to set a specific buffer mode.